# Installing CUPY and Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, cupy

First of all, my system is Windows server 2016 and I have 3 CUDATOOLKIT installed with version=10.1, 11.8 and 12.1. I first installed Pytorch with CUDATOOLKIT=11.8 and it worked. Then when I tried installing CUPY with command:
conda install -c conda-forge cupy
CUPY worked but Pytorch stopped working.
I realized that CUPY installation messed up (I don't know how) my CUDATOOLKIT. So I started over, reinstalling ANACONDA. Then I tried to install CUPY first with command:
conda install -c conda-forge cupy cudatoolkit=11.8
by forcing it using specific CUDATOOLKIT, but it stuck at "soling environment" for many hours and I had to terminate it.
It seems that the two libraries, CUPY and Pytorch, don't like each other. As I need both of the libraries and I would appreciate it if anyone can help.

I heard that a virtual environment could help. I tried but couldn't get it.
I am hoping that both libraries are working.

Comment: Problem solved. But it may not be the best solution. Here is how. After ANACONDA is installed, Use command: pip install cupy-cuda11x to install cupy. Then run conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia to install Pytorch.